# Randomly get multiple rows from a table

Tags: php, mysql, random

Right now I'm selecting 3 random rows from a table using `ORDER BY Rand();` as pointed out all over the web this method is very slow. I am using it on a database with only 30 rows and it takes a long time to return the value. Most of the other solutions i've found only return one row.  What's the best way to return multiple random rows?

```
$get_projects_query = 
  mysql_query(
    "SELECT p_id FROM project_data WHERE p_featured='1' ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 3"
  ) or die(mysql_error());

while($project_row = mysql_fetch_array($get_projects_query)) {?>
  //Do stuff
} 
//end three random featured projects loop)
```

Comment: @BandonRandon - You should verify which part/method is slow. `order by rand()` would not slow on table with 30 rows only.

Comment: Are you sure it’s actually the query that takes that long?

Comment: @ajreal, I wonder if it's my server being slow then or the fact that I'm loading images. humm.....

Comment: @BandonRandon - yup, images .. how many bytes ? re-think

Comment: @ajreal, not horribly big. Are you thinking `rand()` will be faster than the pulling all the data into a php array and using `shuffle()?

Comment: @BandonRandon - I assume, is shared-hosting ? Any bandwidth throttling? Of course doing in PHP is efficient if you still think order by rand is slow. Some references - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only 30 rows, you have a couple other options.

Option #1

1. fetch all 30 rows.
2. call shuffle()
3. read the first 3 off the pile

Option #2

1. Generate 3 random numbers from 0 to 29. Call them r1, r2, r3.
2. SELECT ... WHERE p_id IN (r1, r2, r3)

Option #3

1. SELECT p_id FROM ...
2. while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) $idList[] = $row["p_id"];
3. shuffle($idList)
4. SELECT ... WHERE p_id IN ($idList[0], $idList[1], $idList[2])

Comment: Option #2 has to assume the row primary keys are sequential and without gaps. For such a small number of rows Option #1 seems very reasonable, even storing the results in memcache or similar.

Comment: Certainly. But if there are only 30 rows, you would hope the IDs are monotonically increasing.

Comment: Sorry i'm pretty new at this, with option #3 I'm assuming that $idList is a php array?

Comment: Yes. You create the array (not shown), fill it with the ID numbers from the table (step 2) and then use it to generate the second query.

Answer (score 1):

First select the table count. Order by an index column (probably the primary key). Then select limit 1 with offset = to a random integer in the range of 0 to the table count.

Comment: wouldn't this method only return one result?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 30 rows why not download all 30 rows to your client and then generate 3 random row indexes

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else said. Having only 30 items in your query do like this:

1. do your query without RAND()
2. build an array / object with all the items - E.g.: *items[]*
3. generate 3 random numbers (x1, x2, x3) between 1 and the length of the array and then display them: *items[1], items[2], items[3]*

Or your query has only for the moment 30 results but in time it will be bigger and bigger?

Comment: Right now I only have 5 querys. It's for my portfolio so I don't see it getting much bigger than 30 that would be a lot of projects to look at. I was thinking 30 MAX.